# Zeros of $z^2\cos(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the zeros of this function and their respective orders.

The first thing I did was to use the fact that a product is zero iff each factor is zero, therefore it must occur that $z^2=0$ or $\cos(\frac{1}{z})=0$. For the second factor, we have that $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi.\mathbb{Z}$, none of which is 0, so I can obtain the zeros by taking reciprocals. For the first factor, clearly $z=0$ but this point is not defined in the second factor so I'm doubting if it is a zero.

So I did a power series expansion of the cosine, obtaining $z^2\cos(\frac{1}{z})$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2-2k}}{2k!}$. For $k>2$ clearly $z=0$ fails here too. Thought it would be useful for "cancelling" removable singularities but no go.

So, my question is, is $z=0$ a zero? A pole? A singularity? I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Poles and zeroes both have a well-defined order, about which the function looks like $z^n$ or $z^{-n}$ - this power series clearly has neither.

Comment: @preferred_anon thanks! I learned the definition of zeros as "a zero has order N if the Nth derivative of f is the first derivative that, when evaluated in that point, gives a number distinct from zero". I've never really related that definition to the power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cos(1/z)$ is essentially singular at $z=0$, multiplying it by any power of $z$ cannot give a zero there. You always still have infinitely many negative powers of $z$ in the Laurent series expansion, so the essential singularity remains:

$\cos(1/z)=1-(z^{-2}/2)+(z^{-4}/24)-(z^{-6}/720)+...$

$z^2\cos(1/z)=z^2-(1/2)+(z^{-2}/24)-(z^{-4}/720)+...$

Comment: Thanks! I was fixed on the idea that a point can be both a zero and a singularity, for example z=1 in $\frac{(z-1)^2}{(z-1)}$, but I overlooked the fact that here the singularity is removable. 

So, can I affirm that if the singularity is essential, that same point can never be a zero?

Comment: By definition an essential singularity is never a zero, and multiplying the function by a power of $z-z_0$ (where $z_0$ is where you are looking) never removes the infinitely many negative powers in the Laurent expansion. The multiplication works only for poles where there are only finitely many negative powers to be canceled out.